# How to set video stretch in to parent size in javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am trying to play a video using javaFx.I don't know how to fit the video in to the correct size of parent. When i click the maximize button of the window, video goes to the left corner of the view. How to make it responsive? some one please give me a good idea to make it possible.

```
 public class ServerController{

    @FXML
        private BorderPane mainlayout;

    public void loadVideo(){
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            final File f = new File(workingDir,"/src/main/resources/video/video.mp4");
            final Media m = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
            final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(m);
            final MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
            final DoubleProperty width = view.fitWidthProperty();
            final DoubleProperty height = view.fitHeightProperty();
            width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(view.sceneProperty(), "width"));
            height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(view.sceneProperty(), "height"));
            view.setPreserveRatio(true);
            mainlayout.getChildren().add(view);;
            player.play();

            }
}
```

I will call "loadVideo()" method to set the video view. Rest of the codes are excluded for the purpose of brevity.

fxml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainlayout" minHeight="720.0" minWidth="1280.0" styleClass="welcome-border-pane1" stylesheets="@../css/fextile.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">  
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will take care of everything

```
MediaView.getParent().layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable, Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {
            mediaView.setFitHeight(newValue.getHeight());
            mediaView.setFitWidth(newValue.getWidth());
        }
    });
```

Whenever your `Parent`'s size is changed or `Stage` is `Maximised` it your `MediaView` will adjust accordingly